# How can i fix search field in php

Tags: php

I am searching for the past few hours for a solution and i cannot find.

I am building a website and on a page i have a search box like you can see in the photos.

This is the code for the field

```
  <h3>SEARCH HERE  </h3>
  <h7 id="xxxnot" style="color:#FF0000; padding-left:3px;"> </h7>
</section>
<section>
  <label class="input"> <i class="icon-append icon-tag"></i>
  <input size="35" id="samplees" type="text" name="samplees" required="required">
  </label>





\`your text\`
```

There will be other values (PHP pages OR HTML pages ). The files will be created manually.

For example I create a PHP page with the name `1111.php`, when someone enters `1111`, to show the `1111.php` page.

If I create another page with the name `2222.php` , who ever enters `2222` to show the `2222.php` page.

Thank you

Comment: What's the question? Where's the photo(s)? Maybe you're looking for rewrite rules? You want user to enter `example.com/1111` and get directed to `example.com/1111.php` or have the content of that file load for the `/1111` slug?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is not clear.  Please elaborate on what you are trying to ask, including information about the problem you are observing and what specifically isn't working as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to create a link to yours "EXISTENT" pages (Nothing will be created by the server, you will need to create manually.

[Glob Function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) works well on this

Pass the value of your input to another page (search.php) (I will use GET method, in this demo

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
   <input size="35" id="samplees" type="text" name="samplees" required="required">
</form>
```

After this use the glob fuction with the value

```
$sampless = $_GET['samplees'];

$glob = glob('/'.$sampless.'.php');

foreach($glob as $g){
    echo '<a href="">'. $g[].'</a>';
}
```

In this demo I only create a  to make a link to the page, you can customizea you want.

Tips: You can read about [ajax and jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) if you want to create this search in the same page